# NavigationView не закрывается

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

У меня есть `DrawerLayout`, в котором есть `ToolBar`, `NavigationView` и список. `NavigationView` правильно открывается, но при попытке закрыть его, он не реагирует на нажатия. Вот **код разметки**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_color"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:title="PRIVET"
        android:background="#29b6f6" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/nd_head"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mRelative"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

А вот код **активити**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> myDataset = getDataSet();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `DrawerLayout` должно быть всего два потомка - меню левое и основной контент экрана. У вас же их 3. Попробуйте переместить `AppBarLayout` в `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Точно, я и забыл про это. Наверно, всё таки, лучше сделать отдельно DrawerLayout(Recycler view) и фрагмент. А во фрагмент уже прятать списки и т.д. да?

Comment: @DenisMolodec, не очень вас понял. В navigationView можно список отобразить кнопок. А остальное во фрагменте.